# deposits of post-dated checks in the bank, which the bank will deposit on the deposit date?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, india, check, deposits

Many Israeli banks let their customers give them post-dated checks, which they will hang on to, for an extra fee, and deposit at the deposit date.

Does this option exist in other countries as well (such as the US, India, or the UK)? If who, what is this service called?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes in quite a few countries. You would have to specify the countries of interest for a meaningful answer.

Comment: Hi Dheer - information on the banking systems in the US, India or the UK would be appreciated...

Answer (score 3):

In the US, I could not say whether there is some bank that will do this, but my personal experience has been that these checks are always declined until the date becomes current or they are cashed immediately despite being post-dated.  I've never been offered any service to hold it and deposit it later.  That spans at least 3 banks in 2 states.  Of course that's a small sample and someone else might have specific information for what you want at a specific bank.

See also: [Does a post-dated check have any *valid* use for delaying payment?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/33693/does-a-post-dated-check-have-any-valid-use-for-delaying-payment)

Answer (score 2):

In India Post Dated Check [PDC's] are provided by almost all banks to Corporate Customers. This facility is not provided to individual retail customers.