# Should I expect a receipt when giving a post-dated cheque?

Tags: canada, check, receipt

I gave my landlord some post-dated cheques for rent spanning the next 6 months and wasn't given any receipts. It was explained that they don't give out receipts until the cheque has been processed/cleared now.

This means I'll get a receipt each month. I'm not entirely comfortable issuing payment without a receipt, previous landlords (and this one) have given receipts for post dated cheques. This is a new practice compared to previous years.

**Should I ask for *something* acknowledging that they at least have the cheques or do I require a real receipt?**

Maybe a formal letter or statement saying that they got the cheques? I'm just worried that if they ever got lost I wouldn't have anything saying I at least delivered them.

Comment: Why are you issuing checks for future payment?  Will you not be around to send payment?

Comment: No, only options are cash or debit (which I have conflicting work and travel hours) at their office and cheques. No pre-authorized debit or things like that to make it easier.

Comment: @SaultDon: That still doesn't totally explain why you're giving a bunch of postdated checks at once.  Can't you just mail in a check each month?

Comment: I've never heard of a receipt for any check.  Your cancelled check is your receipt.

Comment: @brian You've never shopped at a supermarket, then?

Comment: @BrenBarn I give a bunch because I planned out an annual budget and it was easy to write them all at once while I was sitting in one spot.

Comment: @Brian Is a cancelled cheque the same as a cheque that's been processed or cashed?

Comment: Yes, when a check is cashed, the bank stamps it and used to return it to you if asked.  Nowadays I think all banks just post an image online.

Comment: @PeterK.  Sometimes receipts are given no matter what the payment method.  I mean specifically for a check.  ps. you must be older than me :)

Comment: @brian Get off my lawn! ;-)

Comment: Their policy seems reasonable to me.  After all, a receipt is usually an acknowledgement of *payment*, and a post-dated check isn't a payment, not until its date arrives.

Comment: You can get a receipt for *anything*.  (Any "object" if you will.)  Of course, naturally, you can get a receipt for the fact that you gave them some particular instrument (a "post dated cheque" - or whatever).

Comment: "Should I ask for something acknowledging that they have the cheques or do I require a real receipt?"  The "something" acknowledging that they have the cheques, is a "real receipt".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you want a receipt.

Imagine the scenario that next month you don't send in the payment, because you already gave it to them. Then they send you a bill for the late fee. Now you call them up and ask what happened. Their response would be "what check?"

Or they start the procedure to evict you...

Or their bank might decide to cash the checks despite the date written on the check...

This happened to my wife a long time ago. Just before leaving for Christmas break she sent in the rent due on January 1st . It was so early that it wasn't in the pile of January payments, so they thought she didn't pay. It was easy to fix, once she asked them to look for the check. They set it aside so they wouldn't cash it early, then they forgot about it. A receipt might have helped get them to look for it.

Answer (score 1):

The check is not legal tender until the date on the check! In effect, you have not paid him in advance.  Therefore, the landlord does not owe you a receipt until the money is in his possession. Issuing postdated checks is not a good idea. If you had paid him with one check for the whole six months, you definitely would be entitled to a receipt for that.

Comment: +1 Also you could stop payment before the cheque was cashed.

Answer (score 0):

You do know that the bank doesn't care about the date on the check right? I would be very careful doing that. The bank will cash the check when it gets deposited no matter what the date on the check is.  I think you would be better off setting up automatic payments from your bank.

Edit: I just noticed you are in Canada so I'm not sure the same rules apply but I would still verify that the banks will honor the date on the check.

Comment: From the answer here - http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/33693/does-a-post-dated-check-have-any-valid-use-for-delaying-payment - in Canada if the bank pays the cheque early you can claim it back up until the day before the date.